# how to use of labels in lisp need help please

Tags: list, lisp

as far as I understoon the use of labels is to define a local function the same as flet but with higher scope. is that correct. I will provide an example:

```
(defun nested-average (tree)
  ;labels are the same as flet but with higher scope, define local functions
  (labels ((%nested-average
                ;arguments for the function
                (branch sum visited)                
                (cond
                 ((consp branch)
                      (multiple-value-call
                      ;calls the previous function with reference to the label
                       #'%nested-average (rest branch)
                       (%nested-average (first branch) sum visited)))

                   ;is branch a number
                 ((numberp branch)
                    (values (+ sum branch) (1+ visited)))
                  ;otherwise
                 (t 
                 (values sum visited))
                 )
            )
           )
            (multiple-value-call #'/ (%nested-average tree 0 0))
    )
)
    ;(nested-average ' (10 ((30 1) 20) (8 (5 (50 7)) 9) 40))
```

Comment: ... and the question is...? The code, as posted, works fine for me, yieling a result of `18` given your test data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the Hyperspec: labels is equivalent to flet except that the scope of the defined function names for labels encompasses the function definitions themselves as well as the body.

What this means practically is that labels allows you to write recursive functions. For example:

```
(defun fact (n)
  (labels ((rec (x)
             (if (< x 1) 
                 1
                 (* x (rec (- x 1))))))
    (rec n)))
```

This function works fine, but the same function written with flet will cause an error because the symbol rec will not be bound in the function definition. The sample function you provided would cause an error if it was written with flet for the same reason.